# nginx rewtire doesn't work

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite from short name to FQDN.

My nginx version is 
nginx version: nginx/1.13.4

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name    foo foo.bar.com;
  rewrite_log on;
  rewrite ^ https://foo.bar.com/ permanent;
  include includes/web-site;
  include includes/files-site;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name foo.bar.com
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_certificate foobar.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key foobar.key;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  include includes/web-site;
  include includes/files-site;
}
```

No effect. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to redirect non-ssl traffic to ssl server. if so, you can try this

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   foo.bar.com;
    rewrite       ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

refer https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx

Comment: It didn't help too unfortunately.